# Problem getting HTML to display after forEach loop

Tags: javascript, json, api, foreach

Hope Someone can help out. The goal of this small project is to search the moviedatabase OMDB, and display the fetched results below the search bar. I have a feeling that the code breaks when I try to use the forEach loop on the returned results, but I cannot find the bugs. Every help is appreciated! Thanks!

```
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

      httpRequest.onload = function() {
        if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
          if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
            var response = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText).Search;
            var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
            response.forEach(function (element, index) {
             body.appendChild(" <img src="+element[index].Poster+"/>" +
              "<p>Title: <a href = 'https://www.imdb.com/title/"+element[index].imdbID+"' >" +element[index].Title+ "</a></p>" +
              "<p>Year: "+ element[index].Year+"</p>" +
              "<p>Type: "+element[index].Type+"</p>");
          });



          } else {
            console.log(httpRequest.statusText);
          }
        }
      };


      httpRequest.onerror = function() {
        console.log(httpRequest.statusText);
      };


var searchMovie = function () {
  var input = document.querySelector('input').value;
  if (input) {  


          httpRequest.open('GET', 'https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=' + input + '&plot=short&apikey=b7da8d63');
          httpRequest.send(null);

}
};
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName()` returns node list and not only one node, so you need to get the first one which is the body element, better yet use `.querySelector("body")` or even `document.body`

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the error that you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example which assumes that you're getting back an array of movies.

```js
const response =  JSON.parse('{"Search":[{"Title":"The Town","Year":"2010","imdbID":"tt0840361","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTcyNzcxODg3Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMTUyNjQ3Mw@@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Ghost Town","Year":"2008","imdbID":"tt0995039","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTQyODQ4MzYxN15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTQ1MDczMw@@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Cougar Town","Year":"2009–2015","imdbID":"tt1441109","Type":"series","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTQyMDI2MDM5NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwOTcyNDE5MDE@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"New in Town","Year":"2009","imdbID":"tt1095174","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMzAxNzU4MDE1Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTQ0NDcwMg@@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Mr. Deeds Goes to Town","Year":"1936","imdbID":"tt0027996","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNzdiMDVkNmMtNDI0Ny00MTQ5LWEwNjAtODQxOGNjOTZmMGVmL2ltYWdlXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMDI2NDg0NQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"On the Town","Year":"1949","imdbID":"tt0041716","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNjk0YmVlNTQtZDg0NC00MGYyLWFhYTMtMTBlMzFkYjczMDMyXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMDI2NDg0NQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"The Town That Dreaded Sundown","Year":"2014","imdbID":"tt2561546","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTUwNzUyNjEwM15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwOTk3MTc2MjE@._V1_SX300.jpg"}],"totalResults":"1588","Response":"True"}');

// Get the body, which is the first element in the array
//  returned by document.getElementsByTagName()
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var movie;
response.Search.forEach(function (element) {
  // Create a new element to append
  movie = document.createElement('div');

  // Add HTML contents to new element
  movie.innerHTML = 
              "<img src="+element.Poster+"/>" +
              "<p>Title: <a href = 'https://www.imdb.com/title/"+element.imdbID+"' >"+element.Title+ "</a></p>" +
              "<p>Year: "+element.Year+"</p>" +
              "<p>Type: "+element.Type+"</p>";

   // Append new element
   body.appendChild(movie);
});
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

          httpRequest.onload = function() {
            if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
              if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
                var response = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText).Search;
                var body =document.getElementById('main')
               body.innerHTML = ""
                //document.getElementsByTagName("body");
                response.forEach(function (element, index) {
                var img=document.createElement('img')
    img.src=element.Poster

    var p1=document.createElement('p')
    p1.textContent='Title :'

    var a=document.createElement('a')
    a.textContent=element.Title
    a.href=`https://www.imdb.com/title/${element.imdbID}`
    p1.appendChild(a)

    var p2=document.createElement('p')
    p2.textContent=`Year: ${element.Year}`

    var p3=document.createElement('p')
    p3.textContent=`Type: ${element.Type}`

    var div=document.createElement('div')
    div.appendChild(img)
    div.appendChild(p1)
    div.appendChild(p2)
    div.appendChild(p3)
                 body.appendChild(div);
              });



              } else {
                console.log(httpRequest.statusText);
              }
            }
          };


          httpRequest.onerror = function() {
            console.log(httpRequest.statusText);
          };


    var searchMovie = function () {
      var input = document.querySelector('input').value;
      
      if (input) {  


              httpRequest.open('GET', 'https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=' + input + '&plot=short&apikey=b7da8d63');
              httpRequest.send(null);

    }
    };

    searchMovie();

    var eve = document.getElementById("myInput");
    
    eve.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    
      if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      searchMovie();
      }
    });;
```

```css
.input{
position: fixed;}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input" id="myInput" name="country" value="time" ><br><br>

    <span id="main"></span>
```